# mutt, smime, decrypt with one of two different keys

Tags: email, thunderbird, mutt, smime

This is an odd one.

We want to have an encrypted e-mail list. There are a few ways to do this, but in the interim what we've done is created a public/private keypair via openssl for our e-mail list (list@foo.org) and then distributed the public/private keypair amongst the list participants (ugh). When someone posts to the list, they encrypt using the lists public key, and everyone has the private key (ugh) so it 'works'.

MUAs like Outlook and Thunderbird work with this setup. Mutt has a problem though - it seems to only decrypt a SMIME message with a private key that is specified by your e-mail. So when someone sends an e-mail to the list e-mail, my MUA won't decrypt it.

How can I tell Mutt about this second private key?